# Pass function to child component ANGULAR 5

Tags: angular

I have a component "Calendar" and its child "Month".

```
export class MonthCalendarComponent  {
  @Input() holidayClicked: (day: Date) => Observable<boolean>;

 dayClicked(day: CalendarMonthViewDay): void {
    this.holidayClicked(day.date).subscribe(isHoliday => {
      if (isHoliday) {
        delete day.cssClass;
      } else {
        day.cssClass = 'cal-day-selected';
      }
    });
    // console.log(this.selectedDays);
  }
}
```

I have a method in which I want to use the @Input holidayClicked from CalendarComonent

```
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChildren(MonthCalendarComponent) months: any[];  
holidayClicked(holiday: Date): Observable<boolean> {

    const username = 'user';
    this.holiday.date = holiday;
    this.holiday.stateVal = this.stateSelected;

    this.calendarService.updateEmployee(username, this.holiday).subscribe();

    this.calendarService.updateEmployee(username, this.holiday).map(x => {});
    return new Observable();
  }
}
```

Something is definetly wrong because I get an error "holidayClicked" is not a function.
How can I pass my method in the child component?

Comment: In your `dayClicked()` method, you are calling holidayClicked(day.date) function, and since you have not declared it, it is giving error, change `this.holidayClicked(day.date).subscribe(isHoliday => {})` to `this.holidayClicked.subscribe(isHoliday => {}`

Answer (score 0):

Directly answering your question how to pass holidayClicked as a function to the child components - can be achieved this way:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'calendar',
  templateUrl: "<monthCalendar [holidayClicked]='holidayClickedFunc'></monthCalendar>"
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {}

  public holidayClickedFunc = function(): Observable < boolean > {
    return new Observable();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'monthCalendar',
  templateUrl: './MonthCalendar.component.html'
})
export class MonthCalendarComponent {
  @Input() holidayClicked: Function;

  constructor() {
    this.holidayClicked();
  }
}
```

You could instead just emit an event from your child component to the parent component like so:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'calendar',
  templateUrl: "<monthCalendar (open)='apply($event)'></monthCalendar>"
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {}

  public apply(): Observable < boolean > {
    return new Observable();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'monthCalendar',
  templateUrl: './MonthCalendar.component.html'
})
export class MonthCalendarComponent {
  @Output() open: EventEmitter < any > = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}
  open() {
    this.open.emit(null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you must use .bind like this:

```js
export class MonthCalendarComponent  {
public theBoundCallback: Function;
public theCallback(holiday: Date){
    ...
  }
public ngOnInit(){
    this. theBoundCallback = this. theCallback.bind(this);
  }
  

  @Input() holidayClicked: Function

 dayClicked(day: CalendarMonthViewDay): void {
    this.holidayClicked(day.date).subscribe(isHoliday => {
      if (isHoliday) {
        delete day.cssClass;
      } else {
        day.cssClass = 'cal-day-selected';
      }
    });
    // console.log(this.selectedDays);
  }
}
```

```html
<child [holidayClicked]="theBoundCallback"></child>
```